# Need to add a countdown timer on an AlertDialog and execute a method if there is no response after 2 minutes

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a timer on my AlertDialog so that if there is no response after 2 minutes, it will go to a method.

```
private void AlertMe() {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("We detected an unexpected collision");
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you need medical assistance? If you don't respond within 2 minutes, I will notify everyone on your emergency contacts.");
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Requesting Emergency Services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                CallServices();
            }
        });
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Request for Emergency Services Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialogBuilder.show();
    }
```

I tried adding a countdown timer but I couldn't stop the timer with the **alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton**
How can I implement it? Thanks.

Comment: "I couldn't stop the timer..." -- Set the instance of `CountDownTimer` as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Top of your file

```
private AlertDialog alertDialog;
```

then

```
private void AlertMe() {
        CountDownTimer timer= new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                if(alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()){
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                    CallServices();
                }
            }

        };


        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("We detected an unexpected collision");
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you need medical assistance? If you don't respond within 2 minutes, I will notify everyone on your emergency contacts.");
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(YesProfileUpdate.this, "Requesting Emergency Services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                CallServices();
            }
        });
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                timer.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(YesProfileUpdate.this, "Request for Emergency Services Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialogBuilder.show();
        timer.start();
    }
```

Comment: I tried using your code but the AlertDialog doesn't close after the specified amount of time in CountDownTimer.

Comment: You know you can edit an existing answer right? You don't have to add a new one to make edits...